# ECDSA_nistP384 vs ECDSA_secP384 vs ECDSA_P384 Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, ecc

The windows certificate store, during the creation of a request, gives the following options for the private key:

> *ECDSA_nistP384,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

> *ECDSA_secP384,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

> *ECDSA_P384,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

As far as the standards go, these are all the same curve. What are their differences in the KSP?

Comment: You are asking the same type of question over and over. Please condense.